# Rails: Intermittent Missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

Using: Rails 3.0.3 & Heroku & Exception notifier & New Relic etc.

I am trouble shooting a lot of intermittent problems that seem to occur at my site. Using Exception Notifier I get reports on Missing Template from pretty much all places on the site. The website performs calculations and when I try a calculation that failed for my user it works fine. It seems to work fine for most users as well. Below is some of what I extract from Exception notifier:

```
A ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in calculations#result:

 Missing template calculations/show with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:js, :"application/ecmascript", :"application/x-ecmascript", :"*/*"], :locale=>[:se, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rpm/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_disable_x_sendfile/app/views", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/formtastic-2.0.2/app/views"
 .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/paths.rb:15:in `find'
```

But, maybe I am confused here, what is really a template. In my world, the template is e.g. show.html.erb.

Reading on the web, Stack overflow I am guided to think there is something wrong with how I call the template.

I basically use a controller "result" that performs the calculations and then render the show-template with:

```
    render :show
```

Is that wrong? If so, how come it works (most of the time)?

No matter what, how should I go about to trouble shoot this further because I can't see what is going wrong? Do you need more data from Exception Notifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for a javascript template: `show.js.erb`. If you're making a javascript request you'll need to generate a template for this format as well as `html`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says Rails is looking for a template in "in view paths '/app/app/views'". Thats not where it should look for it.
I am having the same issues here. Wierd. Didn't found out yet.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same error and it's hard to find info about it.